# Value unexpectedly changes while sending from jsp to javascript function

Tags: javascript, jsp

I have a piece of code in jsp:

```
String temp=new SimpleDateFormat("MMddyyyy").format((java.sql.Date)ppdates.get(authShown));
out.print(temp);

<select id="pcol<%=i%><%=weekNo%><%=au%>" onChange="pSelectedAuth(<%=i%>,<%=weekNo%>,<%=au%>,<%=currentEmployee%>,<%=temp%>)">
```

This prints `06042012` on the screen.

Now, my javascript functions are below:

```
function pSelectedAuth(formID,weekNo, index, currentEmployee,startDate){
alert(formID+":"+weekNo+":"+index+":"+currentEmployee+":"+startDate);
```

onchange, this alert shows `1623050`
Does anyone has any idea how to get my `06042012` back?

Comment: check your html source and see what the value is

Answer (score 1):

You're not doing anything to quote your arguments (that is — you're not wrapping them in `'...'` or `"..."`), so they're being interpreted as JavaScript expressions. In JavaScript source-code, `06042012` is interpreted as a base-8 integer (because of the leading `0`), so it denotes 1623050.

To fix this, be sure to wrap your JavaScript strings in `'...'` or `"..."` (as well as to properly escape any internal quotation-marks, backslashes, newlines, special characters, `</`, and so on). That way, you'll have `'06042012'` or `"06042012"`, which JavaScript will interpret as a string, like you want.